# Get lastest updated record for each value inside column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 model: Product, ProductMeta and Product Type.
A Product can have ProductMeta and a ProductMeta has only one ProductType.

I have this inside my ProductMeta table with this fields

[image]

I'd like to have a query in my method
`public static Show (Product $product){ }` where I get the most recent record for each type_id.

So for example: I have `product_id  = 1`
I want the most recent record for each type_id
For `type_id = 1`  I'll have record 1
For `type_id = 2`  I'll have record 24
and continue like this

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model implements HasMedia
{
   use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

   public function metaProducts(){
       return $this->hasMany(ProductMeta::class);
    }
.....
}
```

ProductMeta Model

```
class ProductMeta extends Model implements HasMedia{
     use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    public function product(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
     }
    public function productType(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class,
          'type_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

ProductType

```
class ProductType extends Model{
    use HasFactory;

    public function productMeta(){
       return $this->hasMany(ProductMeta::class,
        'type_id');
    }
....
```

}

Thanks!!!

Comment: Take a look to the [Has One Of Many](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) relation, the *latestOfMany()* or *ofMany()* methods should work for you